# Assigning item's pointer created in constructor to class atribute

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

Class.h :

```
class Main_manager
{
    public:
        Main_manager();
        ~Main_manager();
        Field_manager* field_manag;
    }
}
```

Class contructor:

```
Main_manager::Main_manager() {
    Field_manager* field_manager = new Field_manager;
    this->field_manager = field_manager;
}
```

I thought that *this->field_manager=field_manager* would keep the pointer to the just-created field_manager object as an attribute of Main_manager class, and so I would be able to use its methods.

if I try to call

```
Main_manager::function()  {
    this->field.manager->function_call();
    //trying to call field.manager's method as i should have its pointer
}
```

It does not work. The application break due to unability to read the memory.

`this>field.manager = field_manager` probably does not work. After the constructor is over, `Main_manager` cannot read the memory for `field_manager`.
I thought that if I keep the `field_manager`'s pointer as a class attribute everything would be fine.

Comment: Does `Field_manager* field_manager = new Field_manager;` result in an exception or yields a `nullptr`?

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that this->field_manager=field_manager would keep the pointer

You don't have to do these:

```
Field_manager* field_manager = new Field_manager;
this->field_manager = field_manager;
```

Instead in the constructor, simply allocate your pointer member directly:

```
field_manager = new Field_manager;
```

Comment: Why not simply `Field_manager field_manager?` What's the advantage of `new` for that case?

Comment: thank you very much.
so in this problem I depicted over there, all these items were destroyed after the construtor was over, weren't they?

Comment: No, only the pointer in the constructor that happens to have same name as the class member got destroyed. The memory that you have allocated remains allocated, and the Field_manager object is still alive, although unreachable. You have a memory leak. The pointer of  the class member never gets initialized (not even to nullptr) and contains garbage. Dereferencing it results in undefined behaviour. Please look up the terms RAII, member initialization list, smart pointer and rule of three/rule of five to get a better idea of how to avoid these problems.